# Viewing a UHF-algebra by an infinite tensor-product

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I have encountered the definition of a UHF-algebra by an infinite tensor product. 
 And I think I explained it to myself incorrectly.
I would try to explain how I used to think about it by an example of the CAR-algebra $M_{2^\infty}$.

The infinite tensor product $\otimes_{n=1}^\infty M_2(\Bbb{C})$ is defined to be the closure of the elements of the form $A_1\otimes...\otimes A_j\otimes 1\otimes 1\otimes....$ where $A_i\in M_2(\mathbb{C})$ for $1\leq i\leq j$.
Now, let $\varphi_{n+1,n}:M_{2^n}\to M_{2^{n+1}}$ be defined by $\varphi_{n+1,n}(A)=\begin{bmatrix}A & 0\\0 & A \end{bmatrix}$ and $\varphi^n:M_{2^n}(\Bbb{C})\to \varinjlim M_{2^j}(\Bbb{C})$ be the natural maps. Then I tend to think of the above element $A_1\otimes...\otimes A_j\otimes 1\otimes 1\otimes....$ in the inductive limit $(M_{2^n}(\Bbb{C}), \varphi_{n+1,n})$  as identified with $\varphi^j(A_1\otimes...\otimes A_j)$ where $A_1\otimes...\otimes A_j\in M_{2^j}(\Bbb{C})$ as usual.

Why do I think that this is not true:

I'm reading the notes "Separable Exact $C^∗$-Algebras Embed Into the Cuntz Algebra" written by  Paul Skoufranis, and there he proves the following proposition:

> Proposition 6.6 (The Rokhlin Property of the Bernoulli Shift):
>  Let
>   $\sigma$ be the one-sided Bernoulli shift on the $2^\infty$-UHF
>   algebra $A = \otimes_{j=1}^\infty M_2(\Bbb{C})$; that is $\sigma(A_1
>  ⊗A_2 ⊗···)=I⊗A_1 ⊗A_2 ⊗···$.
>  For each $k \in \Bbb{N}$ let $A_k :=
>  \otimes_{j=1}^k M_2(\Bbb{C}) ⊆ A$ (which is a unital
>   $C^∗$-subalgebra). Then for each $ε > 0$ and for each $r ∈ \Bbb{N}$
>   there exists a $k ∈ \Bbb{N}$ and projections
>   $P_0,P_1,...,P_{2r−1},P_{2r} = P_0$ in $A_k$ such that
>   $\sum_{j=1}^{2^r} P_j = I$ and $||\sigma(P_j)−P_{j+1}||<\epsilon$ for
>   $j=0,1,...,2r −1$.

Well, if my explanations above were OK then the Bernoulli Shift is just the identity map, right?
So, there must be something incorrect in my above explanations, and I don't know how I should correct it.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider $M_{2^\infty}$ as the limit of
$$
 (M_2^{\otimes n}, \varphi_n)
$$
where $\varphi_n(x) = x \otimes 1$. Furthermore, we identify elements in $M_{2^n}$ with their images in $M_{2^\infty}$.

Then, for say $x = e_{11} \in M_2$ you get
$$
 \sigma(x) = 1 \otimes x.
$$
But $1 \otimes x \neq x \otimes 1$ and $x \otimes 1 = x$ in $M_{2^\infty}$.